# What is the scope of app.js in node?

Tags: node.js, global-variables

Variables defined using the `var` keyword in App.js in a node application are not put into the global namespace as if you had used `var` in a web page (outside of function scope).

What exactly is the scope of the variables defined using var in app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top scope is the module (i.e. file). Variables cannot go beyond that. Well, there is a hack, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: Nah, more just curious as to how things are scoped.  So is the module/top level app.js file essentially put inside a closure or something?

Comment: It's not a closure. I would call it *isolation*. The only variable visible from outside of the module is `module.exports` variable. Every other variable is local. I'm not sure how the underlying mechanism works in details (probably not implemented in JavaScript). Also there is a `global` variable in each module and whenever you define variable in the main scope it is added to `global`. Therefore `global` is like `window` in browser, except that it is not shared between different files.

Comment: Is there any way to share the main scope with files that are `require`'d in?

Comment: @arcyqwerty Not without hacks. But is there a need? Adding variables to `module.export` is just few more lines, no big deal.

Comment: I just have a bunch of `require x` in app.js that aren't propagated to my modules

Answer (score 1):

Each file is the highest scope which would be `global`

Actually you can use

```
process.env.USER_DEFINED_VAR
```

for globally accessible variable between files

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable declared using `var` is local to the function.

Because javascript's only scope is function scope.